# ionic2 - setTimeout() called 2 times before the duration set

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have `setTimeout` function in `constructor`:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
            public modalCtrl:ModalController,
            public feedsService:FeedsService) 
            {
              setTimeout(function() {
                console.log("delay a bit");

              }, 2000);
            }
```

But I get `delay a bit` 3 times in the console. first 2 times seems to be called immediately when view initiated. The 3rd time is called after 2 seconds.

1. Why is this?
2. How can I get rid of the first 2 times?
3. I want to use `setTimeout` to populate a list of feeds when page loaded. What is the best way to do this other than `setTimeout`?

Comment: Where are you using this setTimeout fn?

Comment: I use it inside the `constructor`.

Comment: even using it in constructor will call it once. As one instance is created per view. There is something in your code that is initiating this constructor 3 times.

Comment: Hmm. I agree. After many tests, I think the delay works right. It seems like everything initiate 3 times at the initiation state.

Answer (score 0):

populate your feed inside ngOnInit(){} or you can use other hooks as per requirement.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Comment: I tried `ngOnInit()` and `ngViewAfterInit()`, both called 3 times. Is it because of my installation have some issue?